# Adding a javaScript array to a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Im trying to add an array to a webpage. I have tried a few different pieces of code show below but none of them work. I would like the output to be similar to a list like:

text1

text2

text3
...

The code I have used so far is:

```
var i;
var test = new Array();
test[0] = "text1";
test[1] = "text2";
test[2] = "text3";

// first attempt
$('#here').html(test.join(' '));

// second attempt
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testList="";
    for (i=0;i<test.length; i++) {
        testList+=  test[i]  + '<br />';
    }
    $('#here').html('testList');
    songList="";
});
```

I am quite new to javaScript so I am not sure if I have just made a small mistake or if Im doing this in the wrong way. Also, above is a copy of all the code in my javaScript file and some places online are saying I need to import something? Im not sure!
Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the JavaScript console? Are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: Not related to the question, but that's a nasty way to create an array. Just use `var test = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have works if you remove the single quotes from `testList`. However, if you would like an actual unordered list you can do this. ([here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5nFy/))

```
var test = new Array();
test[0] = "text1";
test[1] = "text2";
test[2] = "text3";

// first attempt
$('#here').html(test.join(' '));

// second attempt
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testList=$("<ul></ul>");
    for (var i=0;i<test.length; i++) {
        $(testList).append($("<li></li>").text(test[i]));
    }
    $('#here').html(testList);
    songList="";
}); ​
```

Answer (score 7):

Try without quotes:

```
$('#here').html(testList);
```

-or-

```
$('#here').html(test.join('<br />'));
```

---

Another approach:

```
var html = '';                                    // string
$.each(test,function(i,val){                      // loop through array
    var newDiv = $('<div/>').html(val);           // build a div around each value
    html += $('<div>').append(newDiv.clone()).remove().html();   
       // get the html by
       //   1. cloning the object
       //   2. wrapping it
       //   3. getting that html
       //   4. then deleting the wrap
       // courtesy of (http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html)
});

$('#here').html(html);
```

*There might be more code in the latter, but it'll be cleaner in the long run if you want to add IDs, classes, or other attributes.  Just stick it in a function and amend the jQuery.*

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the line

```
$('#here').html('testList')
```

to

```
$('#here').html(testList)
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Then SO is being weird, because vol7ron's answer didn't appear for me until just now despite (re)loading the question a number of times.

Comment: Look at the **answered X mins ago** of each answer, vol7ron's increments first. I have noticed some oddities with SOs new update polling though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I accidentally deleted it - meant to edit it... no worries

Comment: Yes, we get how to read the time.  However, his answer wasn't even on the page until a full refresh was done.  It didn't bubble up like other new answers.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$('#here').html('testList');
```

shouldn't have single quotes around `testList` - you want to use the content of the variable, not the string literal "testList".

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the variable as a string : `$('#here').html('testList');` Pass it without quotes : `$('#here').html(testList);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
    $('#here').html(test.join("<br>"));
});
```